# Allow SFTP access but not SSH access with Active Directory groups (not local logins)

Tags: centos, sftp

So I am building a CentOS 7 server for the specific use of using it as an SFTP server.

We are migrating VM's and the SFTP server is being rebuilt. So we already have an Active Directory Security group named ftpusers that we want to use to be allowed to access the SFTP server on this vm. However we do not want those users to be allowed to SSH to the vm unless they are part of the AD Security group LinuxAdmins. So what I need is how to allow the members of the ftpusers group to only be able to use the SFTP side and not SSH. All documentation I could find talks about local users to do this, however I have close to 1000's users that already have access and do not want to have to set them all up manually on the new Linux server.

Comment: This is not an English language forum, it is a technical forum. If you are discussing configuration items do please post what you have done and the relevant portion of configuration files. Please see our FAQ about how to ask a question.

Comment: On your SFTP server, create your users without a shell. This link shows how to do it. I suspect that CentOS SSH is not significantly different.  https://tecadmin.net/create-sftp-user-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you've already got the AD setup on the CentOS system to allow the ftpusers and LinuxAdmins groups to log in, and populate appropriate groups.  If not, please let me know.

You might be able to do something like this in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Match Group ftpusers
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ChrootDirectory /path/to/sftp/space
```

I also included the ChrootDirectory, if you want to force them to use a Chrooted environment, which much of the documentation suggests as well.  The important part is the ForceCommand, which means that even if they just ssh in, it'll just connect them to an SFTP backend and not a shell.  The other settings just turn off all the other features of ssh.